# ASP.NET Literal WebControl: Why Use PassThrough Mode?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, mobile-website

For an ASP.NET [`Literal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0aw4d5w.aspx) control, is there *ever* any reason to use [`LiteralMode.PassThrough`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.mode.aspx) instead of the default, [`LiteralMode.Transform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.mode.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen any cases where this makes sense, but I suppose it's there for those situations where you want fine-grained control over the transform.

Comment: I don't quite follow - you can manipulate the string before setting `Literal.Text` whether you use `PassThrough` or `Transform`, so what additional control would `PassThrough` give you?

Comment: I'm sure you've read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.mode.aspx - basically PassThrough means you want to ignore built-in .net user agent rendering. I suppose in cases where .net's built in rendering doesn't work on a user agent you could provide your own rendering. You're probably better off creating a browser file for that situation, however.

Comment: I agree, and appreciate the feedback! I'm flummoxed by the very existence of PassThrough - I'm reviewing some code that explicitly declares that its literals should use that mode and would prefer to use Transform. But I want to make sure I haven't overlooked something.

Comment: Yep, like I said - it almost never comes up. If someone set it explicitly I'd try to find some documentation on why they did that! Most people aren't even aware of this property.

Comment: It took a while, but I finally grokked what you were saying, though  it took your first comment to get it through my head!

Answer (score 0):

I've used the `PassThrough` mode two times when I was putting HTML into the Literal control's `Text` property and did not want the HTML to be altered. I cannot remember the exact details, but the `Transform` mode was not suitable because it allowed some unwanted alterations to the HTML.